# Strange output of LLDB

Tags: xcode, lldb

`(char *) text = 0x0dbf3c50 "\x91\xde\x91\xf4\x90\xc1\x90\xc0\x91\xff\x91\xfc\x91\xf1\x91\xfa\x90\xcd\x91\xfc\x91\xf1\x90\xcea\x91\xf3\x91\xf4\x90\xc1\x90\xc0\x91\xf9\x90\xcea\x91\xd1\x91\xfa\x91\xf4\x91\xfb\xd1"`
What does `\xcea` really mean?
Supposed to be `\xce` and `a` in a raw. I expect valid C (Obj-C) literal to be printed in console. If I put this literal into C source code, xcode warns that `Hex escape sequence out of range`. So something is wrong with this literal.
Version of Xcode is 4.6.

Comment: What happens when you type `frame variable text -f a` and then `p text`?  See: http://lldb.llvm.org/varformats.html

Comment: (sorry, you don't need the `p text` bit in my above comment).

Comment: I can't reproduce state of app with such string. But I am sure that command given in comment above will help me. Never heard of such LLDB commands. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

These are hexadecimal escape codes. `\xcea` is actually two characters: one of which the numeric code is `0xce` and the character `'a'`.

Comment: I also supposed so. I expect valid C (Obj-C) literal to be printed in console. If I put this literal into C source code, xcode warns that hex escape sequence is out of range. So something is wrong with this literal.